# How to solve multilib problem on yum update?

Tags: centos7, yum

When I try to update yum on centos 7 I get a multilib error:

```
Errore:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
    cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
    pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:
    
      1. You have an upgrade for libnghttp2 which is missing some
         dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
         solve this by installing an older version of libnghttp2 of the
         different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
         yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
         requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
         --exclude libnghttp2.otherarch ... this should give you an error
         message showing the root cause of the problem.
    
      2. You have multiple architectures of libnghttp2 installed, but
         yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
         If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
         can remove the one with the missing update and everything
         will work.
    
      3. You have duplicate versions of libnghttp2 installed already.
         You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.
    
    ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
    this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
    do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
    much more problems).
    
    Versioni multilib protette: libnghttp2-1.33.0-1.1.el7.x86_64 != libnghttp2-1.31.1-2.el7.i686
```

I tried to get rid of the problem by:

```
sudo yum erase libselinux.i686
```

but that changed nothing.

```
sudo package-cleanup --dupes
```

gives nothing.
If I execute:

```
sudo yum list --showduplicates libselinux
Plugin abilitati:fastestmirror, langpacks
Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the 
configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
```

- base: mirror.airenetworks.es
- city-fan.org: [www.city-fan.org](http://www.city-fan.org)
- epel: mirror.uv.es
- extras: mirror.airenetworks.es
- remi: remirepo.reloumirrors.net
- remi-php73: remirepo.reloumirrors.net
- remi-php74: remirepo.reloumirrors.net
- remi-safe: remirepo.reloumirrors.net
- updates: mirror.airenetworks.es
- webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
  Pacchetti installati
  libselinux.i686                          2.5-15.el7                        @base
  libselinux.x86_64                        2.5-15.el7                        @base
  Pacchetti disponibili
  libselinux.i686                          2.5-15.el7                        base
  libselinux.x86_64                        2.5-15.el7                        base

What should I do to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The issue was apparently fixed by executing:

```
 sudo yum erase libnghttp2.i686
```

After that yum update worked seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this by downloading the nameof.rpm via wget, then yum install nameof.rpm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).